# What scripture says "sandhyAheenaha asuchihi nityam anarhaha sarvakarmasu; yadhanyatkurutE karma na tasya phalamaSnutE"?

Tags: identification-request, sandhyavandanam

I know that SandhyA vandanam is not a Shruthi (veda samhitAs) concept, but is a Smriti & Sutras driven tradition (please correct me if I am mistaken). However, someone threw this verse at me recently & could not tell me where they read this, they said they read it in kanchi kamakoti publication, but that publication did not provide a source of this verse apparently.

If you know source of another variation of this verse with similar meaning, please do answer with that information, I will appreciate it very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Verse is from [Śrī Dakṣasmṛti 2.19-20a](https://www.astrojyoti.com/pdfs/DevanagariFiles/04Daksha_Smriti.pdf)

[image]

However, according to [this version](https://archive.org/details/AshtadashSmriti/page/n373/mode/1up), of Śrī Dakṣasmṛti, this verse appears as 2.23 with a small variation:

[image]

Here instead of **phalamaśnute**, it is **phalabhāgbhavet**.

While, the meaning of this verse is: One who does not perform saṃdhya is always impure and unfit for performing any other rites. Whatever other rites he may perform, he will not obtain the fruit thereof.

**Edit:** The Verse also occurs in [Śrī Brahmavaivartapurāṇa 2.23.25](http://satsangdhara.net/brahmaV/adhyaya-02-23.htm) with a small variation:

> संध्याहीनोऽशुचिर्नित्यमनर्हः सर्वकर्मसु । **यदह्ना** कुरुते कर्म न तस्य
> **फलभाग्भवेत्** ॥

Also, in [Śrī Kūrma Purāṇa 18.28](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_giitaa/vyAsagItAkUrmapurANa.html):

> संध्याहीनोऽशुचिर्नित्यमनर्हः सर्वकर्मसु । यदन्यत् कुरुते **किञ्चिन्न**
> तस्य **फलमाप्नुयात्** ॥

Answer (score 3):

I don't know exactly which scripture has that exact verse, but all dharmashastras and smritis say the same thing.

> Manu 2.103 - न तिष्ठति तु यः पूर्वां नौपास्ते यश्च पश्चिमाम् । स शूद्रवद् बहिष्कार्यः सर्वस्माद् द्विजकर्मणः ॥ १०३ ॥
> But he who does not stand during the morning-twilight, and who does not sit through the evening-twilight, should be excluded, like the śūdra, from all that is due to twice born persons.—(103)

> Baudhāyana-Dharmasūtra (2.4.15).—‘Here are two verses recited by Prajāpati—One who does not worship the Morning Twilight before its advent, and who does not worship the Evening Twilight before its lapse,—how can they be regarded as Brāhmaṇa? Those Brāhmaṇas who worship not the Morning and Evening Twilights, them the righteous king would be free to employ in the works of Śūdras.’

> Dakṣa (Parāśaramādhava, p. 268).—‘The man devoid of the Twilight Prayers is unclean and unfit for all rites.’

> Gobhila (Parāśaramādhava, p. 278).—‘One who knows not, and observes not the Twilight Prayers,—while living—he remains a Śūdra, and on death becomes born as a dog.’

> Viṣṇu-purāṇa (Parāśaramādhava, p. 278).—‘Those who observe not the Morning or Evening Prayers, those evil-minded ones fall into the darkest hell.’

> Kūrmapurāṇa (Parāśaramādhava, p. 379).—‘If one neglects the Twilight Prayers, and devotes his attention to other acts, he falls into ten thousand hells.’

> Yājñavalkya (Parāśaramādhava, p. 379).—‘If a Brāhmaṇa, except when he is ill, omits the Twilight Prayers, he incurs sin and is despised in the world.’

> Atri (Parāśaramādhava, p. 379).—‘Those who, while in good health, observe not the Twilight Prayers,—are wicked and injure the sun.’